# How to initiate a download via AJAX-Call or secure a File on the server with SlimPHP?

Tags: php, ajax, authentication, download, slim

I am developing an AngularJS WebApp with SlimPHP as Backend.

I implemented a basic Token-Authentication (custom HTTP - header "x-myapp-auth"). The token is validated by my "User" middleware on every state change in the app via an AJAX-Call.
There is the need for converting some JSON - Data to XLS, which I do on the server side within SlimPHP.

Now to my question:
How can I

1. either secure my XLS files on the Server with my Auth-Token in Slim so that I can have a default download href to it in my app
2. make the Browser recognize I want to initiate a download, when I open a "XLS Stream" (sorry, I don't know how to describe it better) from my route in SlimPHP.

The output code for (2) would be:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$jsonData->title.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But when I retrieve that output via AJAX, I can't make the browser initiate a file download.

Comment: What if you handle it with a session or cookies?